# Strange Configuration Error in web.config

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following error in my WebApi application:

`An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'MaxCachedResults'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.`

This is my `roleManager` entry in `web.config` and as you can see I am not specifying the `MaxCachedResults` attribute, although I did add this initially, I removed it so it's no longer being used and I'm not sure where it's picking this up from.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="SiteWorksAPI.RoleProviders.MyRoleProvider, SiteWorksAPI" connectionStringName="SiteWorks" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The error happens when I call `var resp = await _httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri)` and inspecting `resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` displays a 'Configuration Error' HTML page with the above error message.

I have tried all of the following with any success:

- Rebooted my PC
- Recycled the application pools
- Restarted IIS
- Cleared down the Tempoary ASP.NET directory

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Castle Windsor was caching an older copy of the web.config file.  After changing the caching options on the `WebRequestHandler` I was able to get the `HttpClient` to pick up the new web.config file.